# What will be the direction of motion of a test charge released at a point in an electrostatic field?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, potential, field-theory

I have recently come across a statement in my book that,  *"when a test charge is released at a point in an electrostatic field, the direction of traversal of the test charge will not be along the field line passing through the point at which the test charge is released."*

Why is this so?  Wouldn't the charge travel along the electric field line passing through the point??
Could someone explain my why the above mentioned statement is true ?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/178467/50583

Comment: I would add that it is Falematte's answer the relevant one. At least, by interpreting *released* as *with zero initial velocity*.

Comment: @GiorgioP. Does Earth follow the Sun's gravitational field lines?  Thankfully: No.

Comment: so if we release it with zero initial velocity , the path traced by the test charge will be along the direction of electric field only, right ???

Comment: No, field line and trajectory will have a common tangent at the starting position, but the trajectory will not coincide with the line fields.

Comment: thankyou for clarifying.

Comment: @JEB I didn't write anything similar. I wrote explicitly  *with zero initial velocity*. Earth's velocity is never zero.